# How is Linguistics SE doing on returning participation?

Tags: discussion

It seems like there is a lot of focus in the meta about recruiting new people, but it doesn't seem like there is a whole lot of returning participation. Many of the questions and answers are either written by one of a few frequent users, or by new people.

This SE could probably reach critical mass just by trying to get people who have already discovered it to return. I'm a good example of that. I had used this SE to ask 1 or 2 questions, but never really touched it. It was frustrating having very little rep because I couldn't comment or anything. Then I got my StackOverflow association bonus and could actually do stuff here, so I came back.

I don't know if there are stats on that, but it seems like it would be worth the effort to recruit people who have already been here to come back.

Comment: Hae you got any ideas?

Comment: Figure out some way to encourage people who have just answered or asked one or two questions to come back and give the site another try. Maybe even if some people just ask questions for the sake of asking questions. I know there's not a whole lot of questions on here I can answer just because I know a lot about *language* and some about actually psycholinguistics because I'm only a sophomore ling major. There's not a whole lot of variety in that regard.